# Create an array with or without `new`

Tags: javascript, constructor

There are two ways to create an array using the array constructor

```
new Array(1,2,3)
Array(1,2,3)
```

I would say that the first (with the `new` keyword) is preferred or is it of no importance ?

UPDATE: In my case I use this type of array construction because I do:

```
new Array(someNum).join('x');
```

Comment: Neither, use a literal: `[1,2,3]`. ;-)

Comment: True,  I've updated my post to show an example of why I'm using this, thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function is meant to be used only as a constructor function, then one can use the common pattern,

```
function ConstructorFunction() {
    // If the current object is not an instance of `ConstructorFunction`
    if (!(this instanceof ConstructorFunction)) {
        return new ConstructorFunction();
    }
    ...
}
```

Something similar to that would be done in the `Array` constructor as well.

**Note:** It is always better to use `new`, if you intend to use a function as a constructor function.

Comment: "*Something similar to that would be done in the Array constructor as well*". Not according to [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-constructor): "*When Array is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it also creates and initializes a new Array object*", so it doesn't test its *this*, it always creates a new instance.